# Spark REST API: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv

Tags: rest, api, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-csv

I have a pyspark file stored on s3. I am trying to run it using spark REST API.

I am running the following command:

```
curl -X POST http://<ip-address>:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "testing.py"],
"appResource" : "s3n://accessKey:secretKey/<bucket-name>/testing.py",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
"environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://<ip-address>:6066",
"spark.jars" : "spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar",
"spark.jars.packages" : "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0"
}
}'
```

and the testing.py file has a code snippet:

```
myContext = SQLContext(sc)
format = "com.databricks.spark.csv"
dataFrame1 = myContext.read.format(format).option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter",",").load(location1).repartition(1)
dataFrame2 = myContext.read.format(format).option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter",",").load(location2).repartition(1)
outDataFrame = dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2, dataFrame1.values == dataFrame2.valuesId)
outDataFrame.write.format(format).option("header", "true").option("nullValue","").save(outLocation)
```

But on this line:

```
dataFrame1 = myContext.read.format(format).option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter",",").load(location1).repartition(1)
```

I get exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource
```

I was trying different things out and one of those things was that I logged into the ip-address machine and ran this command:

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

so that It would download the spark-csv in .ivy2/cache folder. But that didn't solve the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Shashi, there's a question on the answer below - are you able to answer it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I first added spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar on driver and worker machines. and added

```
"spark.driver.extraClassPath" : "absolute/path/to/spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar",
"spark.executor.extraClassPath" : "absolute/path/to/spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar",
```

Then I got following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
```

And then I added commons-csv-1.4.jar on both machines and added:

```
"spark.driver.extraClassPath" : "/absolute/path/to/spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar:/absolute/path/to/commons-csv-1.4.jar",
"spark.executor.extraClassPath" : "/absolute/path/to/spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar:/absolute/path/to/commons-csv-1.4.jar",
```

And that solved my problem.

Comment: I'm using [spark-jobserver] and I face a similar issue. I added `libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.4"` to plugins.sbt file but it didn't help. Any other inputs? Thanks

Comment: I believe this link should be helpful: https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#dependency-jars 

if you choose to use dependent-jar-uris you must upload jars separately on the Driver machine ( I am not sure if you have to upload on worker machine or not)  

I never tried adding dependencies myself while using job-server but this should work

Comment: @Nagesh, see the comment from Shashi K.

Comment: @ShashiK, when remarking to a specific person, please use their `@` handle so they are notified. I've done it for you above.